# Node js, Request body empty for certain websites

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I'm experimenting with Node.js and web scraping. In this case, I'm trying to scrape the most recent songs from a local radio station for display. With this particular website, `body` returns nothing. When I try using google or any other website, `body` has a value.
Is this a feature of the website I'm trying to scrape?

Here's my code:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = "http://www.radiomilwaukee.org";
request(url, function(err,resp,body) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird, the website you're requesting doesn't seem to return anything unless the `accept-encoding` header is set to `gzip`.  With that in mind, using this gist will work: https://gist.github.com/nickfishman/5515364

I ran the code within that gist, replacing the URL with `"http://www.radiomilwaukee.org"` and see the content within the `sample.html` file once the code has completed.

If you'd rather have access to the web page's content within the code, you could do something like this:

```
// ...

req.on('response', function(res) {
    var body, encoding, unzipped;

    if (res.statusCode !== 200) throw new Error('Status not 200');

    encoding = res.headers['content-encoding'];
    if (encoding == 'gzip') {
        unzipped = res.pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
        unzipped.on("readable", function() {
            // collect the content in the body variable
            body += unzipped.read().toString();
        });
    }

    // ...
```